# Query returns wanted rows intill LIKE is added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The SQL:

```
SELECT user_games.PID, 
       games_link.APPID, 
       COALESCE( games_steam.name, games_other.name ) AS name, 
       games_other.logo
FROM user_games
 LEFT JOIN games_link ON games_link.APPID = user_games.APPID
 LEFT JOIN games_steam ON games_steam.APPID = games_link.ST_ID
 LEFT JOIN games_other ON games_other.APPID = games_link.GB_ID
WHERE user_games.UID = 'Cf9nHvOlaaLzFRegX2Il'
```

When I use this query it returns all the rows I want and the rows that should appear when I add the LIKE to it:

[image]

But when I add the LIKE:

```
AND (games_steam.name LIKE '%roller%' 
OR games_other.name LIKE '%roller%')
```

It returns nothing. Anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard for `like` in MySQL -- and almost all databases -- is `%`.  I think you want:

```
AND (games_steam.name LIKE '%roller%' OR games_other.name LIKE '%roller%')
```